# "Launchy" not for Apps but for Windows

Tags: windows-xp, launchy

I am looking for an application that would work like [Launchy](http://launchy.net/), but instead opening applications (shortcuts) it would focus window with entered name. If there are many windows with such phrase in name it should list them, like Launchy does.

Does anyone know of such tool for Windows XP?

**EDIT:** As Ivo pointed out, you can say it would be sort of text queryable Alt+Tab

**MY CHOICE:** I kept Launchy as my quick app launcher (because it's instantaneous and FARR has a minimum but noticeable delay) and will use FARR (with that plugin) as window focuser and an smart file searcher. Thanks for help.

**FINAL UPDATE:** After several days of using FARR I can confirm that it works very good, so I stay with this Launchy+FARR combo.

Comment: You're asking for a smart Alt+Tab ;-)

Comment: Yes. I am :) I am looking for queryable Alt+Tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a little more than you asked for but [FARR](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/findrun/index.html) has a [plugin](http://www.donationcoder.com/Forums/bb/index.php?topic=10988.msg87342#msg87342) that can do this. On top of it you get an excellent app launcher;)

Comment: Looks great. If FARR is stable and doesn't go monster on RAM, it looks like I will say goodbye to Launchy or at least move it to other hotkey.

Comment: Yes, FARR is really great. Been using it myself for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

### [Enso Launcher](http://humanized.com/enso/launcher/)

[image]

Comment: ...but I wish there were a way to change that very green theme...

Answer (score 2):

[PyLaunchy](http://pylaunchy.sourceforge.net/) plugin - which enable creation of **Launchy** plugins with Python and besides it comes with [PyGoy plugin](http://pylaunchy.sourceforge.net/docs/pygoy.html) which do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use autohotkey, with a script that takes an argument and switches to that window. Uploaded [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2502059/Autohotkey%20Scripts/WinSwitcher/WinSwitcher.ahk), and a compiled version for those without AHK [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2502059/Autohotkey%20Scripts/WinSwitcher/WinSwitcher.exe).

It takes an argument, and uses regex to match the window title. I reccomend adding a keyword into your application launcher of choice, and then using it like "switchTo firefox", or "switchTo "Launchy" not for Apps", or so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Tasky](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tasky-launchy/), a Launchy plugin, should do it.

(Although, it apparently doesn't work with Launchy 2.5.)